# How do i write from stream to file without breaking it?

Tags: c#

I have to select file, split it on 10kb, encrypt and send it thru networkstream (tcp).

On server side, I have to receive it, decrypt it and save file on other location.
Code is working and it transfers all bytes with byte[], but if I select image or word document you cannot open it, but they both have the same size.
I am using combination of DiffieHellman and Aes.

Here is Server code:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("D:\\" + name + "." + suffix, FileMode.Create))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Int32.Parse(howManyTimes - 1); i++)
    {
        byte[] data = Receive(ns);
        byte[] decrypted = Decrypt(data, key, iv);
        fs.Write(decrypted, 0, decrypted.Length);
        Array.Clear(data, 0, decrypted.Length);
        Send(ns, ok);
    }

    if (Int32.Parse(rest) > 0)
    {
        byte[] data = Receive(ns);
        byte[] decrypted = Decrypt(data, key, iv);
        fs.Write(decrypted, 0, Int32.Parse(rest));
        Array.Clear(podatki, 0, Int32.Parse(rest));
        Send(ns, ok);
    }

    fs.Close();
}
```

Here is client code:

```
byte[] data= new byte[10000];
var fileStream = file.OpenFile();

using (Stream bufStream = new BufferedStream(fileStream, STD_MSG_SIZE))
{
    for(int i = 0; i < Int32.Parse(howManyTimes); i++)
    {
        bufStream.Read(data, 0, STD_MSG_SIZE);
        Send(ns, Encrypt(data, key, iv));
        Array.Clear(data, 0, data.Length);
        Receive(ns);
    }

    if (Int32.Parse(rest) > 0)
    {
        bufStream.Read(data, 0, Int32.Parse(ostanek));
        Send(ns, Encrypt(data, key, iv));
        Array.Clear(data, 0, data.Length);
        Receive(ns);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you decrypt data on client before sending and get exactly same results?  One of two things are happening 1) You are not receiving all the bytes before decrypting.  2) The key and/or IV is different between client and server.  They must be exactly the same.

Comment: if i send txt file with "something" inside i can open other file and i see "something" inside. But if i send image i just see blank image. maybe it has something to do with encoding?

Comment: How large is the text?  When sending the data you should include a byte count at the beginning and then on receive side loop until all the bytes are received.  TCP breaks messages into max size of 1500 bytes.  Windows will automatically combine messages using timers but on large message you will not receive in one chunk.  So howManyTimes is not always the same due to the splitting and combing of the TCP messages.

Comment: i tried with different size txt files and it works perfect. from 10Bytes to 150MegaBytes. howManyTimes is just a full part so int number (14,5 = 14), then rest is that missing part calculated with fileSize - (howManyTimes*SizeOfBuffer).

Comment: Try remove the fs.Close();  The using block will close and dispose the data.  Or add a fs.Flush(); to the code.

Comment: i tried it and it is all the same.

Comment: Can you use BeyondCompare to find differences between original file and received file?

Comment: I just used BeyondCompare and i saw some differences betwen 2 pictures. XML transfers okey, but the "weird characters" seems to fail. here is a picture of those: https://gyazo.com/ef9e5f5ac02d30f0ee42c594aef3c1bb

Comment: First change the buffer size so it is consistent : byte[] data= new byte[STD_MSG_SIZE];  It looks like you may have an encoding issue.  There is an ASCII header at the beginning of the PDF file.  You can see the differences in the header in beyond compare.  Most likely the data is converted to ASCII.  Open receive file with Notepad and then from menu File:SaveAs change the encoding to UTF-8 and see if the beginning of the file changes.

Comment: I used Convert.FromBase64String and Convert.ToBase64String and it worked. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I do not think the issue is with the posted code.  Suspect issue is in either the send or receive methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in encoding. I used ASCII and it didnt work for strange letters. If you use Convert.FromBase64String and Convert.ToBase64String it works.